# Как в QT убрать рамку приложения из кода

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++17

Есть приложение.
Надо убрать рамку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем сделать это нужно из кода. 
Также интересует - будет ли это работать на других ОС, кроме Windows?

Comment: Будет работать без рамки в больш нстве ОС. Кроме андроид наверное

Comment: @eri я про linux (Ubuntu/Debian) и MacOS

Comment: Там рамка убирается вместе с заголовком. В виндовс можно было убирать заголовок, оставив рамку

Comment: @eri мне нужно убрать и то и то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конструкторе классы окна  `setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)`

Рамка и заголовок окна убирается во всех ОС, где это возможно. Вроде в андроид(десктоп режим) не убирается.